# Canadian Senior Math Contest Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, exponentiation

I was trying to solve the problem below but was completely unable to. My question is that **which general category do questions like these belong to?**. Once, I know that I would go learn the specific math concept and attempt at solving the question.

> For each positive integer $n$, define $a_n$ and $b_n$ to be the positive integers such that
>
> $$\left(\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2\right)^{2n} = a_n + b_n\sqrt 6$$
>
> and
>
> $$\left(\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2\right)^{2n} = a_n - b_n\sqrt 6$$
>
> (a) Determine the values of $a_2$ and $b_2$.
>
> (b) Prove that $2a_n - 1 < \left(\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2\right)^{2n}<2a_n$ for all positive integers $n$.
>
> (c) Let $d_n$ be the ones (units) digit of the number $\left(\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2\right)^{2n}$ when it is written in decimal form. Determine, with justification, the value of $d_1+d_2+d_3+\cdots+d_{1865}+d_{1866}+d_{1867}$ (the given sum has 1867 terms.)

Comment: For a) take n=2 and calculate. You get two equations from it. Solve this system of $a_2$ and $b_2$

Comment: (a) is arithmetic. (b) might be induction. (c) could be Number Theory.

Comment: It is important that $\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2 \lt 1$ so when you raise it to a power it gets small.  Then note that $(\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 2)^{2n}+(\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2)^{2n}$ is an integer because the terms with square roots in them cancel.  This is a recurring theme in olympiad problems.

Comment: Look at the units digits of both $a_n$ and $b_n$ for small $n$ (say, through $n=5$) and see if you notice anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call all of these algebra, but this is definitely competition math algebra. These are solvable by expanding through binomial expansion (and I believe this is the intended solution).

If you need more hints, ask below.